# Locating an EventHandler through Application Usage C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm converting a program from visual basic to C#, and in order to test it I need to change the configs so that when a menu option from a menu that appears after a right-click is pressed it calls the C# code I created rather than the old Visual Basic code. Obviously, that means locating the event handler. Unfortunately, I don't know the name of the menu option being pressed and have yet to guess what it is. Is there a way for me to run the application, and have the program pause (like a breakpoint) at the very first thing it does after the menu-option is pressed in the application? Right now I have a breakpoint on the first line of the method that is run. But is there a way to find the eventHandler that triggers that method, by running the program? Or is there another option to help me find what's triggering it?

Comment: If you have the source code, why can't you open the form in the designer and see the name of the button? If you don't have the source code, what are you setting the breakpoints on?

Comment: When program is not running click on the button.

Comment: @GSerg I don't know which designer it would be as there are several designers and the option appears only after a right click (just edited the question to reflect the part about the right-click. My apologies, it was misleading before)

Comment: @jdweng I thought of that but I'm dealing with a button that appears only after a right-click, so it doesn't appear in the designer (just edited the question to reflect the part about the right-click. My apologies, it was misleading before)

Comment: The button is then being added dynamically.  So you have to find the code that adds the button and then find the event handler.  Maybe just searching code for += will work.

Comment: @Michael Then open the designer of the form that displays the menu, and it should have a `ContextMenuStrip` at the bottom.

Comment: VS IDE has a pause button you can use during debugging.  Hitting that at the right time will allow you to inspect the call stack.  Or you could put a breakpoint at a location you know is executed before this button click and then step though until you get to the desired methods